# Rewrite traditional for loop to streams.map java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i am trying to test a `Rest API` `PUT` request. It is a spring boot application.
`PUT` request is used to do an update in the existing list of objects

traditional way of writing is working.

`data` is the data in the memory - which is a `List<Bean>` and 
`name` (string type) is the key to find the object in the data and `objectBean` is the one to replace once we find with the key(that is `name`)

```
public void update(Bean objectBean, String name) {

    for(int i = 0; i < data.size() ; i++) {
        Bean l = data.get(i);
        if(l.getName().equals(name)) {
            data.set(i, objectBean);
            return;
        }
    }   

};
```

but i tried to write using Stream in java 8 . below is the code

`Data.stream().map(p ->  p.getName().equals(name) ? objectBean: p );`

but this gives empty list.

Comment: This code looks for a specific object in `data`, modifies it and bails-out. This is not a good use-case for [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)...

Comment: is there any other way to do this using any Java 8 features ? instead of traditional way of updating the data ?

Comment: There's not much benefit you'll get from syntactic sugar. That said, this looks like it should have been a `Map<String, Bean>`.

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: @Goo Did you mean `data.add(i, objectBean)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `streams` here makes code only more complicated.

If you really wants you can introduce it to find the index `i` value. After that you can do the replacement.

```java
IntStream.range(0, data.size())
    .filter(i -> data.get(i).getName().equals(name)).findFirst()
    .ifPresent(i -> data.set(i, objectBean));
```

Comment: You don’t need the curly braces, `.ifPresent(i -> data.set(i, objectBean));` will do

Answer (score 0):

Given that `data` is some List with `Bean` objects, you'd need to return your collected stream:

```
return data.stream()
  .map(bean -> bean.getName().equals(name) ? objectBean : bean)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `data` is a non-empty Iterable then the output must be as well as `map` takes a `Function` object. However, this is not a good use case for the `Stream` API:

Firstly, streams are designed for side-effect-free purposes (i.e., creating new data structures rather updating them). The stream API supports `forEach(Consumer<super T>)` which is designed for side effects, but so do many other collections, in fact, all Iterables, whereas the immutable operations such as `map` and `flatMap` are not.

Second, I can't see the rest of your program, but at least in this snippet you seem to be updating your data structure based on the name, and you assume the name is unique because you stopped as soon as you reached the first `Bean` with the name you're looking for. Consider using `Map<String, Bean>` as your data structure.

Lastly, `streams` are lazy data structures, meaning that all the chained operations get computed when you collect. This provides incentive to chain a lot of computations together - chaining just a single `map` doesn't give you any performance advantages (tho it does give you referential transparency).

Answer (score 0):

```
return data.stream()
    .filter(bean -> bean.getName().equals(name))
    .findAny()
```